# Nginx rewrite - only redirect to one domain

Tags: url, redirect, nginx

I am looking to redirect all requests that match http://s.domain.com to redirect to http://domain-new.com

I have the following and it seems to redirect all requests to the second domain.  I would only like to redirect on an exact match.

```
 if ($request_uri ~ "s.domain.com"){
       rewrite ^ http://domain-new.com;
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a server block for the subdomain and redirect that to the new domain

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name s.domain.com;
    rewrite ^ http://domain-new.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This should work for only redirecting the index:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name s.domain.com;
    # for index.xyz pages
    location ~ ^/index\..+$ {
        rewrite ^ http://domain-new.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    # for pages with index left out
    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ http://domain-new.com permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dayo I am sorry, I failed to mention that the subdomain is on a different platform all together (IIS / ColdFusion).  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I see. In that case, you'll normally need to add the redirect rule to the platform it is on. Is nginx and the other platform on the same server?

Comment: The servers are in different locations.  1. IIS / Windows on seperate IP and 2. NGINX On another IP.   I thought I was headed in the right direction by looking for an exact match on s.domain.com but it was not working as expected. I also know I can do this with a simple js script but feel doing this server side is the best way. and I am making attempts at learning nginx :)

Comment: In that case, this is not an nginx question but an IIS one. What you want to ask about is how to redirect on IIS. If the subdomain is on IIS on a different machine and IP, any request for that subdomain will be hitting that different machine. I am sure you can imagine how given that, adding any instructions relating to this subdomain on the Nginx machine can never work.

Comment: Thank you but I may have not explained properly because I am a bit confused.  How could I ever do a route all requests to s.domain.com to another domain if s.domain.com is pointing to the nginx server.  All the requests coming into domain-new.com are being handled correctly.  I just want to redirect the index only on s.domain.com (NGINX) to domain-new.com (IIS)

Comment: Updated the answer. Server block for s.domain.com to redirect to domain-new.com wherever that may be.

Comment: Hey @Dayo - Thanks for bearing with me on this. the issue is that I only need to redirect requests that match "s.domain.com" to the t.  So the index page only.  All other pages should work as they are currently setup.   Any idea on how to do this?